# Plot of a function involving an integral taking forever

Tags: plotting

I am new to Mathematica so apologies if the issues are trivial.

I am trying to plot the function as attached in the code, and it is taking forever.

I solved a differential equation numerically with no issues, whose solution is Eqq99 = z[w][t] (where w is a parameter and t is a variable). Then I'm taking a sort of Fourier Transform of the solution and trying to plot it.

```
Eqq97[w_]=(w/(2 \[Pi]))*Integrate[(z[w][t] /. Eqq99)*Sin[w t], {t, 20, 30}]

Plot[Evaluate[Abs[Eqq97[x]]], {x, 0.5, 2}]
```

The first line of code executes but the second line runs forever. How can I sort this?

Edit: Here is the full code.

```
\[Lambda] = 0.5;
F = 1;
w0 = 1;
\[CapitalGamma] = 0.6;

Eqq99 = ParametricNDSolve[{z''[t] == -2 \[CapitalGamma] z'[t] - 
     w0^2 (1 + \[Lambda] Sin[2 w t]) z[t] - F Sin[w t], z[0] == 1, 
   z'[1] == 0}, z, {t, 0, 1000}, {w}]

Eqq97[w_]=(w/(2 \[Pi]))*Integrate[(z[w][t] /. Eqq99)*Sin[w t], {t, 20, 30}] 

Plot[Evaluate[Abs[Eqq97[x]]], {x, 0.5, 2}]
```

Comment: 1) Use `NIntegrate` not `Integrate`. 2) How complicated is Eqq99 ? 3) You can control the number of points that plot uses e.g by doing `PlotPoints->10` and `MaxRecursion->0` to reduce the number of slow integral evaluations.

Comment: Without executable code to work with, we cannot do much.

Comment: Your code evaluates the integral for every point (w). If the integral can be done analytically with a formal "w", the result can be used inside the definition of "Eqq99".  If not, "NIntegrate" will be faster.

Comment: Have you looked at `ParametricNDSolveValue`? It's usually the better way to solve DEs with parameters.

Comment: @flinty Thank you! That worked. I used `NIntegrate` and followed your point (3)  and got a plot.

Comment: @BobHanlon I have added the full code, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

λ = 1/2;
F = 1;
w0 = 1;
Γ = 3/5;

Eqq99 = ParametricNDSolve[
   {z''[t] == -2 Γ z'[t] - 
      w0^2 (1 + λ Sin[2 w t]) z[t] - F Sin[w t],
    z[0] == 1, z'[1] == 0}, z, {t, 0, 1000}, {w}];

Eqq97[w_?NumericQ] := (w/(2 π))*
  NIntegrate[(z[w][t] /. Eqq99)*Sin[w t], {t, 20, 30}]

AbsoluteTiming[
 Plot[Abs[Eqq97[x]], {x, 1/2, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 3,
  ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image]